# Adding Azure AD authentication to existing .Net MVC app: id_token not being validated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I'm trying to add Azure AD authentication to a .Net MVC app that currently uses individual user accounts. I've setup the app registration in Azure, and installed and configured OpenID Connect.

In Startup.cs I've added:

```
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

// app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    // Sets the ClientId, authority, RedirectUri as obtained from web.config
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = authority,
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    // PostLogoutRedirectUri is the page that users will be redirected to after sign-out. In this case, it is using the home page
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    Scope = OpenIdConnectScope.OpenIdProfile,
                    // ResponseType is set to request the id_token - which contains basic information about the signed-in user
                    ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
                    // ValidateIssuer set to false to allow personal and work accounts from any organization to sign in to your application
                    // To only allow users from a single organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and 'tenant' setting in web.config to the tenant name
                    // To allow users from only a list of specific organizations, set ValidateIssuer to true and use ValidIssuers parameter
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true // Simplification (see note below)
                    },
                    // OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications configures OWIN to send notification of failed authentications to OnAuthenticationFailed method
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed
                    }
                }
            );
```

And in `web.config` I've set authentication type to None

```
<authentication mode="None"/>
```

I've then added an action method to trigger the challenge:

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "http://localhost:54465" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
}
```

I can still login to the app with individual user accounts (I'd like to keep this as an option), but can't sign in with Azure AD. The user gets redirected to the Azure AD login screen, logs in, and I can see the response coming back with id_token, but never authenticates in the app.

I'd understood this is supposed to happen automatically within the OpenID Connect middleware, but is there anything else that needs set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a clean project using the same Azure app registration and it worked as expected, so started comparing the clean project against my old one. In the very early days of the project it used SimpleMembershipProvider, and even though the project had since been changed to use ASP.Net Identity the WebMatrix dlls were still being referenced and included in the build.

[image: WebMatrix project references]

Removing these references, cleaning, and re-building has solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Remember to set `RedirectUri` which is same with your app registered in azure ad.

I test with your code and could authenticate in the app. In Azure ad app registration, click `Authentication` and choose `Id Token`.

[image]

You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp) and download sample about adding Microsoft identity platform sign-in to an ASP.NET web app.

Comment: Hi Joey. Have checked and the RedirectUri matches between the Azure app registration and what's being passed into the Open ID auth options in Startup.cs. Had enabled ID Tokens in Azure - I can see the id_token being returned and if I decode it manually can see it is valid. The link you posted is the one I've been using but I must be missing something.