# Azure AD with Identity in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have an app where I used to authenticate users using AD along with Identity. But now I want to change from AD to Azure AD.

I registered an app in Azure portal and added the this in my `appSettings.json` file

```
 "AzureAD": { 
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "XXXX",
    "TenantId": "XXXX",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignoutCallbackUrl": "/signout-oidc"
  }
```

I also Added this code in my `StartUp` class

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) 
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
            services.AddRazorPages()
                 .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Now when I run the app it still takes me the login page I had before instead of Microsoft login page. So I removed the `AccountConttroller` along with Account Folder in the Views.

But it still doesn't work. And shows like this.

```
This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44353/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
HTTP ERROR 404
```

If I create a new app and add the same code in `StartUp` and `appSetting` it works fine but in my projects it doesn't.

What is the problem here??

Comment: Is this package installed on the project?

Microsoft.Identity.Web

Looks like it's trying to find the Redirect URI but there just isn't a page there, this page is typically [provided by the above package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/microsoft-identity-web).

Comment: Yes I have this package installed. but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @[DCCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8333554/dccoder)

Installed the following  `Nuget package`  to the project   **`Microsoft.Identity.Web`** & **`Microsoft.AspNetCore.authentication.AzureAD`**   in the `Nuget package` installer from root of your project:

[image]

In  `startup.cs`  file and update under the configuration services as below

```cs
      public  void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
        services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection(****"AzureAd"****));
  
         services.AddControllersWithViews();
    
    }
```

And update the authentication as below:

**`app.UseAuthentication()`;**  app.UseAuthorization();

[image]

And in  **`appsetting.json`**  file and updated the below details which noted from above overview of App registration.

```json
{
"AzureAd": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
"Domain": "demotest.onmicrosoft.com",
"ClientId": "*****",
"TenantId": " ****** " ,
"CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
},
```

[image]

From  `homecontroler.cs`  file added a attribute called  **`[Authorize]`**

[image]

And run the application which will redirect to MSA login page as below :

[image]

For more information please refer this [SO THREAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60711795/adding-azure-ad-authentication-to-existing-net-mvc-app-id-token-not-being-vali) & [Blog](https://dotronald.be/add-azure-active-directory-to-an-existing-asp-net-mvc-web-application/)

UPDATE: Also Please try to add the below code in your `startup.cs`

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
       endpoints.MapControllers();
     }
     );
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply. No I actually did all of this but still it didn't work with me. I even created new project and I added all code needed and it worked but then when I added my other controller and views to the new project it says that localhost url is not available

Comment: Could you please refer the blog that shared in answer.

Comment: I did refer to it. I did the same but had to change a bit because I'm using dotnet Core, But I still get this error `This localhost page can’t be found
No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44353/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
HTTP ERROR 404
`

Comment: Could you please try to add this code in  `startup.cs` class 

    pp.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    }
    );

Comment: Also please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43468715/asp-net-core-this-localhost-page-can-t-be-found &  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59949443/how-to-fix-error-404-when-logging-out-on-an-asp-net-core-mvc-app-against-azure-a

Comment: Hello @r2000_na , I have updated the answer . If the provided solution worked could you please accept it as an answer to help other community members for similar issues. Thanks:)